# To determine $\alpha,\beta$ such that $\frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\to{0}}$

Tags: limits

Let S be the set of $(\alpha,\beta)\in{R}^2$ such that $\frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\to{0}}$ as $(x,y) \to {(0,0)}$.

Then S is contained in the set

1.{$(\alpha,\beta):\alpha>0,\beta>0$}

2.{$(\alpha,\beta),\alpha>2,\beta>2$}

3.{$(\alpha,\beta),\alpha+\beta>1$}

4.{$(\alpha,\beta),\alpha+4\beta>1$}

$if \alpha=\beta=1$ , $\lim_\left(x,y\right)\to {(0,0)}\frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_\left(x,y\right)\to {(0,0)}\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$ hence option 2 wrong.

along y=mx , $\lim_\left(x,y\right)\to {(0,0)}\frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=lim_{x}\to{0}\frac{m^{\beta}{x^{\alpha+\beta-1}}}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}=0$ only if $\alpha+\beta>1$

along $y=mx^4$ , $\lim_\left(x,y\right)\to {(0,0)}\frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=lim_{x}\to{0}\frac{m^{\beta}{x^{\alpha+4\beta-1}}}{\sqrt{1+m^2x^6}}=0$ only if $\alpha+4\beta>1$

hence option 3 and option 4 are correct.

how to conclude for option 1?

Comment: You might want to change to polar coordinates.

Comment: Typo: $$x^\beta\to y^\beta$$

Answer (score 0):

Take $x=r\cos{\theta}$ and $y=r\sin{\theta}$ and you have:

$\frac{x^ay^b}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=r^{a+b-1}(\cos{\theta})^{a} (\sin{\theta})^b$

Because we have trigonomtric functions in the above relation then $a,b$ must be at least possitive.

Secondly we must have $a+b>1$

Also $a,b$ cannot be of the form $\frac{m}{k}$ where $k$ is even and $m$ is odd.

The set where the limit exists and is zero is $B= (\{(a,b)|a+b>1\} \cap \{(a,b)|a,b>0\})$ \ $\{\frac{m}{k}|k$ even and $m$ odd $\} \subseteq \{(a,b)|a>0,b>0\}$

Comment: Should be $r^{\alpha + \beta -  1}(\cos \theta)^{\alpha + \beta}$

Comment: Oh yes you are right..i will edit it.thank you

Comment: Or, do not propagate the typo in the question?

Comment: why a and b cannot be of the form {$\frac{m}{k}\vert$k even and m odd} .can we conclude for option 1 without using polar form.

Comment: take for instanse $\sqrt{(\cos{\theta})^3}$..it is not defined for $\theta=\pi$

Comment: No we can't  choose option 1 because if you take for instance  the path $(t,t)$ then for $a=b=1/10$ then $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{t^{a+b}}{\sqrt{2}t}$ does not exist

Comment: @MariosGretsas sorry to disturb you after this long time.. in the question it is asked "then $S$ contained in"... clearly `your answer`$\subset$`option 1`

Comment: OK if it is so, then it's option 1..i will edit my answer.